# Where does nbconvert store the intermediate .tex file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am converting a jupyter notebook to pdf using Anaconda prompt

```
jupyter nbconvert my-jupyter-nb.ipynb --to pdf
```

The prompt says that a notebook.tex file is created. How do I access that?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`notebook.tex` is created as an intermediate/temp file. If you also want the LaTeX output, then use `--to latex` in a separate command.

```
jupyter nbconvert my-jupyter-nb.ipynb --to latex
```